Question on deleting Docker containers/images
I had a problem deleting files from Docker Desktop.. my disk was with 24GB Free, and after deleting everything from D.Desktop, i will have 40GB less.. but it stayed on 24GB of free space.. like i deleted nothing.. someone know what can i do? It seems like i deleted from docker desktop but stayed on my pc
Tried deleting everything from Docker desktop and expected to free some GBs on my disk                               ..                                                                                                                                  .

What exactly did you delete? Containers? Images? Volumes?

Everything, i wanted to leave docker from 0, so cleaned up every container, image and volume. I used devcontainers from vscode to download everything, i found this dir but i dont know where is located:
""Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/remote-test-b2bc866420b26832b3aa40988143f0b313307bb5ea84db5174884bb74ad5c1f3/_data",  
"Name": "remote-test-b2bc866420b26832b3aa40988143f0b313307bb5ea84db5174884bb74ad5c1f3","


looks like at least one volume is still present. Do you get some volume when you run docker volume ls?

Yes, i dont know how to make this as a markdown to be more readable sorry

And what happens if you try to delete this volume (docker volume rm b2b)? If docker says that a container is using this volume, you may want to investingate what containers are still present (docker ps -a).

Error response from daemon: get b2b: no such volume

oh, sorry. Read this as id, but the name is remote-test-b2b.... Try docker volume rm remote-test.

run this command docker system prune -a this will delete everything !!!

Please be aware that this command will delete all containers, images, and other Docker objects that are not currently in use. Make sure you don't have any important data or containers you wish to keep before executing this command. Once executed, it cannot be undone, so use it with caution.

Yes, that's what I said in my comment It'll delete everything !!!

Yes, you're correct, that was an oversight.
